# Probability of failure of first unit provided that at least one of the two units has failed

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The following question was asked in JEE Main 2021:

> An electric instrument consists of two units. Each unit must function independently for the instrument to operate. The probability that the first unit functions is $0.9$ and that of the second unit is $0.8$. The instrument is switched on and it fails to operate. If the probability that only the first unit failed and second unit is functioning is $p$, then $98p$ is equal to:

My attempt:

Let us call the event of the first unit **not** functioning $A$ and the second unit **not** functioning $B$. Let the event of failure of the instrument be $F$. Then $P(F) = 1 - 0.8 \times 0.9 = 0.28$.

From Bayes' Theorem:

$$P(A|F) = \frac{P(F|A) P(A)}{P(F)} = \frac{1 \times 0.1}{0.28}$$
$$P(B|F) = \frac{P(F|B) P(B)}{P(F)} = \frac{1 \times 0.2}{0.28}$$
Hence, $$p = P(A|F) \times (1 - P(B|F)) = \frac{10}{98}$$
And the answer should be $98p = 10$. However, the given answer is:

> $28$

Where did I go wrong?

---

The solution given by many websites online is:

$$p = \frac{P(A) \times (1 - P(B))}{P(F)} = \frac{28}{98}$$

Although this arrives at the correct answer, this method is not really convincing, and my method seems to be the right method to me. However, I can't arrive at what exactly is wrong in this solution (or mine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While $A$ and $B$ are independent, you have *incorrectly* assumed that they are independent conditional on $F$, which is not true. Instead, we have

$$p=P(A,B^c|F)=\frac{P(F|A,B^c)P(A,B^c)}{P(F)}=\frac{P(F|A,B^c)P(A)P(B^c)}{P(F)}=\frac{1\times 0.1\times 0.8}{0.28}$$

so $98p=28.$

Comment: I understand how this solution works, but I still don't understand where I went wrong; is the value of $P(A|F)$ and $P(B|F)$ which I arrive at wrong?

Comment: @AshishAhuja You went wrong here : $ p  = P(A|F) \times (1 - P(B|F)) $

Comment: @AshishAhuja $p=P(A,B^c|F)$ but this is **NOT** the same as $P(A|F)P(B^c|F)$ unless $A,B^c$ are **conditionally** independent (conditional on $F$)

Comment: Ah ok, I got it. Another way of saying the same thing is that $P((A\cap F) \cap (B^C \cap F)) = P(A\cap F) \times P(B^c \cap F)$ is only true if $A \cap F$ and $B^c \cap F$ are independent, which in this case they aren't, correct?

Comment: @AshishAhuja No, that is not the same thing. Also, how would you expect $A\cap F$ and $B^c\cap F$ to be independent in general in the first place when they both involve $F$? Please look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence).

Comment: Ok yes, I got my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishAhuja sure no prob

Answer (score 1):

Both of $P(A|F)$ and $P(B|F)$ are meaningless **unless event $F$ actually happens**, so you need to multiply them both by $P(F)$, which gives

$$P(A|F)P(F)\times(1-P(B|F)P(F))$$

and then divide by $P(F)$ to give you the conditional probabilty.